# How to implement groupBy on multiple keys(columns) in Apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I'm using Python and I want to implement groupBy over multiple columns in Apache beam. For example  I have a below dataset with 3 columns :

GM TV   7500.2 abc
ONLINE  2000.1  def
CONSOLE 1000.2  ghi
CONSOLE 6500.6  ghi
GM TV   4500.5  abc
CONSOLE 9500.4  ghi

How can I group the data based on first an third column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tuple `(column 1, column 3)` as key in your GBK transform.